# training and testing image data with neural network tool in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, neural-network, decision-tree, knn

My original pictures are gray scale 200x200x3.

1. I have downscaled them to 50x50x3.
2. They are mug shots of 100 different people. I have taken the copy of 30 of them, and corrupted, and put back in the same image matrix cell, and it became 130 pictures.
3. Afterwards, I have created a 130x7500 array which involves each picture as a row. Then, I have classified that matrix into training and test data set. Then, classified the divided data using MATLAB decision tree tool, and knn tool. Now my question is, how to manage it by using neural network tool.
4. And I have a classification matrix 130x1.

If I want to do the same thing using neural network tool, what I should do?

Comment: At the level you are describing your process, you do exactly the same with a neural network, except for step 3 swap "knn and decision tree" with "neural network". That doesn't seem to be what you are asking, though. What problem are you facing?

Comment: net = fitnet(10);
net = train(net,clusterMatrix,classification);
view(net);
y = net(clusterMatrix);
perf = perform(net,y,classification);                                                             This is my code, and I get the error:  Inputs and targets have different numbers of samples.

Comment: clusterMatrix's dimension is 130x7500 (each row is one picture) and classification matrix is 130x1.

Comment: I cannot see where you have split into training and testing classes (step 2) in your code? Is it possible you have a mistake there, and one of your matrices does *not* have the size you think? What do `size( clusterMatrix )` and `size( classification )` show if you print them just before your network training code?

Comment: Actually, that is also another problem, I don't know where to use test and training data in this tool, so that's why I just put my X and Y to see whether  can I take a prediction classes matrix?

Comment: Not sure if I can answer more because I don't use that specific NN toolkit. However, I think the following would help someone else answer: Edit in the code plus comments you have tried to the question, add the full error message, and explain which line it is referring to. You probably need to split the matrices into train/test sets manually e.g. `rp = randperm(130); train_clusterMatrix = clusterMatrix( rp(1:100), : ); test_clusterMatrix = clusterMatrix( rp(101:130), : ); train_classification = classification( rp(1:100), : ); test_classification = classification( rp(101:130), : );`

Comment: I have already split the data.